# Service: receive message from inner static broadcast

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I want to call a function im my service class when I press the headset button. Therefor I needed to implement a static inner broadcast class into my service. But now I cannot access the local field of the MediaPlayer that is currently running because I have to stay static. I tried it with observable but that didnt work either. [Like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083430/communication-between-broadcastreceiver-and-activity-android?answertab=active#tab-top)

I tried also to make the field itself static, but in the logic I want to implement, I need a function that switches songs so I would have to set the playlist also static and that is not acceptable for me.

```
public class MediaService extends Service implements
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

private IntentFilter intentFilterMediaButton = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
private MediaButtonReceiver mMediaButtonReceiver = new MediaButtonReceiver();

public MediaPlayer player;

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    registerReceiver(this.mMediaButtonReceiver, this.intentFilterMediaButton);
    player.start();
}

static int xTime = 0;
public static class MediaButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            return;
        }
        KeyEvent event =   (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event == null) {
            return;
        }
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (action){
                case 0: // Button down
                    xTime++;
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(xTime == 1)
                                //MediaService.mediaControlAction(xTime);
                            if(xTime == 2)
                                //MediaService.mediaControlAction(xTime);
                            xTime = 0;
                        }
                    };
                    if(xTime == 1)
                        handler.postDelayed(run, 500);
                    break;
            }
        }
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[Eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

I added following to my Service

```
private EventBus eventBus = EventBus.getDefault();
this.eventBus.register(this);

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.BACKGROUND)
public void onEvent(MediaActionEvent event){
    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(event.getxTimesPressed()) + " times pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Called the Event in my Broadcast

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(xTime == 1)
                                EventBus.getDefault().post(new MediaActionEvent(xTime));
                            if(xTime == 2)
                                EventBus.getDefault().post(new MediaActionEvent(xTime));
```

And created a new Class for the Event

```
public class MediaActionEvent {
private final int xTimesPressed;

public MediaActionEvent(int xTimesPressed) {
    this.xTimesPressed = xTimesPressed;
}

public int getxTimesPressed() {
    return xTimesPressed;
} 
}
```